# how to remove avhdx file?

Tags: hyper-v, vhdx

I use Windows Server 2012 Hyper-V role.
I accidentally pressed the "Snapshot" on a running VM.
During the creation of snaphost, I clicked "cancel". 
The operation of creating a snapshot is successfully canceled, but is now VM used avhdx file instead of my vhdx file.
The snapshot is not visible for this VM. 
I turned off the VM after this and nobody used it. 
How do I return to using my vhdx file without data loss?

Answer (score 2):

You should delete the Snapshot through Hyper-V Manager.

If that is not an option the next best solution is to create a new Snapshot and then delete the Snapshot after the creation finishes. That will combine the Snapshots and roll them up into the vhdx file.

If that does not work then you can try to manually merge the avhdx file and vhdx file. This can result in data loss if something goes wrong so don’t try this unless other options (such as the above but not only the above) do not work.